# Why doesn’t this hotkey configuration for Sublime Text work?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have configured <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to open a file in my browser, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> when the editor is focused on some HTML page, it doesn’t work. Why not?

[image]

**more details**:

what makes me confused is that this ctrl+b works if it is combined to other command such as close, but why not openInBrowser command, so does st2 support this command, how to know whether it support this command or not?

**Edit 1**:

you may find **openInBrowser** command in this link http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands

**Edit 2**

@MattDMo what is the corresponding name of command then, i cannot find them in its official document http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/

Comment: Where did you find this `openInBrowser` command? It isn't part of the base Sublime installation.

Comment: @MattDMo replied in Edit 1

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is to the docs for Sublime Text 1. Those commands have all been renamed in ST2 and ST3...

Comment: @MattDMo replied in edit 2

Comment: @MattDMo maybe i should use its api <http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html>, but which function is corresponding to openInBrowser, confused

Comment: while I commend you for editing your question repeatedly to add new information, if someone asks you a question in a comment you can usually just answer in a comment...

Comment: No, you don't want the API

Comment: @MattDMo which command i should use then? <http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/index.html> find no corresponding command which could be used as openInBrowser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `open_in_browser`, not `openInBrowser` (which is an old Sublime Text 1 command). So, your keymapping should work with that. However, if you weren't already aware, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> is already mapped to the `Build` command, used for running [build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html). It's not a very good idea to overwrite built-in commands, especially one as important as this one, so I'd suggest changing your keybinding to:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "open_in_browser" }
```

This isn't in use by any of the default Sublime commands, although some plugins may use it.

Comment: wow, cool, how do you find this command? i cannot find it even using search engine <http://cn.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asublimetext.com+open_in_browser>, no exact match in fact. neither i can find it with this link <http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/index.html>

Comment: @worldhello - try using the ["Unofficial" Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html), they have much more information than the official site. However, `open_in_browser` isn't there, either. The quick answer is I've been working with Sublime for a rather long time, and know pretty much all of its ins and outs, so I knew how the command should be formatted `using_python_snake_case` instead of `usingCamelCase`. I just did a "Find in Files" in `Packages/Default` for `browser` and found it mentioned in a couple of places, including the plugin file `open_in_browser.py`. (continued)

Comment: The plugin's main class is, by convention, named using `PascalCaseCommand`, in this case `OpenInBrowserCommand`, which translates to a `"command"` name `open_in_browser`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: also @worldhello, if my answer helped solve your problem, please indicate it by marking it as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to it. We'll both get reputation points from it, and with your 3 points you'll have 15, which will allow you to upvote the answer as well, if you choose. Please see [What is reputation?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more info.

Comment: i have marked it as answer:) one more staff, how to specify which browser to use instead of using the default one when using open_in_browser command :)

Comment: one more question  in the new thread, if you are interested, have a look:) <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276143/can-i-create-my-own-command-in-sublime-if-yes-how-to-associate-python-implemen>