# Can I create my own command in sublime and how to associate python implementation to that command?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

One more depth into my former question [Why doesn’t this hotkey configuration for Sublime Text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029242/why-doesn-t-this-hotkey-configuration-for-sublime-text-work). Now I come to the implementation of sublime command, it is really a confusing way to hack what commands sublime has, as the exploration in former thread in order to find the command which is used to open a browser, finally I found it with help of @MattDMo.

Then I find there is one file named open_in_browser.py in the Packages/Default folder, I guess the commands is just the file name of .py files, **but in fact I cannot find the corresponding file which could be named find_pre.py to command find_prev**, then I copy open_in_browser.py as open_browsers.py, and  add **{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "open_browsers"}** to sublime keymap, but it doesn't work. Then I realized that there should be some place which registers sublime commands to their implementation, so if there is such a mechanism, what is it? Where can I find it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Create a file with any name in the `Packages/User` directory. Create a class in the file like `MyTestCommand` with a `run` method. Create a keymap using the class name in snake case and without `Command` suffix. Use named arguments to pass anything to the command.

**Full answer**

There is no need to register anything to create custom commands. Filename doesn't matter as Sublime Text simply scans it's directories for `.py` scripts and automatically executes them (registers them).

Here is the example script I use:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ChangeViewCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, reverse=False):
        window = self.window
        group, view_index = window.get_view_index(window.active_view())
        if view_index >= 0:
            views = window.views_in_group(group)
            if reverse:
                if view_index == 0:
                    view_index = len(views)

            if reverse:
                new_index = view_index - 1
            else:
                new_index = (view_index + 1) % len(views)

            window.focus_view(views[new_index])
```

So what it does - switches to the next/previous tab in the current group (the default behavior circles around all tab groups).

So we simply save it as any name in `Packages/User` directory.

Then we must create the key bindings in our user keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "change_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+tab"], "command": "change_view", "args": {"reverse": true} },
```

As you may see, the command is `snake_case` of the class name without the `Command` suffix. This will run the class's `run` method with named arguments.

Does this answer your question? For debugging in case of any errors - open the ST console (default shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>)